# Conversion from NED to 'flat earth' coordinates.

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

I have a flat earth problem of a missile that needs to return to launch pad. The solution to this problem (using convex optimization in case you are interested) is then meant to be fed to a simulator that uses a NED spherical coordinate system. It also uses longitude latitude and altitude. What I need to do is be able to freely convert between the two coordinate systems.

From: http://walter.bislins.ch/bloge/index.asp?page=Globe+and+Flat+Earth+Transformations+and+Mappings

Conversion from geographic flat earth to cartesian flat earth is the following:

$X=(\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi)R(cos(\lambda))$

$Y=(\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi)R(sin(\lambda))$

$Z=(\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi)R(h)$

$\phi$ is the latitude and $\lambda$ is the longitude.

but this doesn't seem right to me as the altitude (Z) will then explode as you are multiplying the radius of the Earth $R$ by the altitude $h$.

Edit: To better explain the conversion, I begin with a stationary observer at the launch pad on the Earth that is considered the origin and target for the missile. This then has to be converted into a flat earth definition where the distances projected on the Earth are considered as the x and y distances in the flat earth problem. These distances, in my intuition, should be distances formed from the minor circle arcs, that is the longitudinal and latitudinal lines from the observer, and the point the missile makes on the ground.

[image: Flat Earth distances as viewed on the spherical Earth]

Comment: Since the earth is not flat, your "flat earth problem" seems rather pointless.

Comment: @Tetragrammaton the flat earth problem is used as an approximation. It is not 'useless'.

Comment: An "approximation" to what? Again: Earth isn't flat. Neither approximately nor accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to represent the downrange and crossrange with the equations above to determine how far it was from the launch pad in metric distances. For the algorithm, the inputs required where just the distances in the ECI frame (x,y,z).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about a conversion between a [local tangent plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates) coordinate system and a spherical coordinate system, which is not pointless and is widely used in academia and industry.  And you're right that Walter Bislins' solution would result in units of length squared for the Z component.  You could just use the root sum square for Z, but that would most likely be in reference to the center of the planet, so you'd need to subtract either an approximate planet radius or calculate the [reference ellipsoid height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_ellipsoid) at each lat/lon.

This is an old post so I'm sure you figured that out by now.